# Order of base classes and super() usage in multiple inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, super

Could you please help me to understand the difference between these two cases?

```
class B1:
    def f(self):
        super().temp()

class B2:
    def temp(self):
        print("B2")

class A(B1, B2):
    pass

A().f()
```

It prints `"B2"`.

If we switch `B1` and `B2`:

```
class A(B2, B1):
    pass

A().f()
```

I get `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'temp'`

Comment: What is confusing you? `B2` doesn't implement `f`, so if it's looked up there first (in the second case) it can't be found.

Comment: I guess the OP doesn't understand why the order of the arguments to class A matters here, or what effect the ordering has.

Answer (score 2):

Python uses something called [C3 linearization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization) to decide what order the base classes are in: the *"method resolution order"*. This has basically two parts when stated informally:

- The path must hierarchy must never go down from a class to its superclass, even indirectly. As such, no cycles are allowed and `issubclass(X, Y) and issubclass(Y, Z)` implies `issubclass(X, Z)`.
- The order when not forced by the rule above is ordered by number of steps to the super-most class (lower number of steps means earlier in the chain) and *then* the order of the classes in the class lists (earlier in the list means earlier in the chain).

The hierarchy here is:

```
    A
   / \
  /   \
B1     B2   # Possibly switched
  \   /
   \ /
  object
```

In the first case the order after C3 linearization is

```
  super    super    super
A   →   B1   →   B2   →   object
```

which we can find out with:

```
A.mro()
#>>> [<class 'A'>, <class 'B1'>, <class 'B2'>, <class 'object'>]
```

So the `super()` calls would resolve as:

```
class A(B1, B2):
    pass

class B1:
    def f(self):
        # super() proxies the next link in the chain,
        # which is B2. It implicitly passes self along.
        B2.temp(self)

class B2:
    def temp(self):
        print("B2")
```

so calling `A().f()` tries:

- Is `f` on the instance? No, so
- Is `f` on the first class, `A`? No, so
- Is `f` on the next class, `B1`? Yes!

Then `B1.f` is called and this calls `B2.temp(self)`, which checks:

- Is `f` on the class, `B2`? Yes!

And it is called, printing `B2`

In the second case we have

```
  super    super    super
A   →   B2   →   B1   →   object
```

So the  resolves

So the `super()` calls would resolve as:

```
class A(B2, B2):
    pass

class B2:
    def temp(self):
        print("B2")

class B1:
    def f(self):
        # super() proxies the next link in the chain,
        # which is B2. It implicitly passes self along.
        object.temp(self)
```

- Is `f` on the instance? No, so
- Is `f` on the first class, `A`? No, so
- Is `f` on the next class, `B2`? No, so
- Is `f` on the next class, `B1`? Yes!

So `B1.f` is called and this calls `object.temp(self)`, which checks:

- Is `f` on the class, `object`? No,
- There are no superclasses, so we have failed to find the attribute.
- Raise `AttributeError("{!r} object has no attribute {!r}".format(instance, attribute_name))`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is simply the order of classes in MRO of class `A` in both cases:

```
class A1(B1, B2):
    pass

class A2(B2, B1):
    pass

print(A1.mro())
print(A2.mro())
```

Which returns:

```
[<class '__main__.A1'>, <class '__main__.B1'>, <class '__main__.B2'>, <class 'object'>]
```

and

```
[<class '__main__.A2'>, <class '__main__.B2'>, <class '__main__.B1'>, <class 'object'>]
```

Now when you call `A1.f()` or `A2.F()` the attribute is found in `B1`, and there you call `super().temp()`, which means call `temp()` on the next class found(or move on to class next to it not until `temp` is not found and so on..) in `MRO`.

As the next and only class in case of `A2` is `object` which has no `temp()` method an error is raised.

In case of `A1` next class after `B1` is `B2` which has a `temp()` method, hence no error is raised.